# Saving environment data frames to csv files

Tags: r

In the environment, I have 100 `data.frames` that are imported from `xls`. 
Ex.

```
a <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100))
b <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100))
c <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100))
```

I want to save all these `data.frames` as `.csv` files. As I have 100 `df` in the environment I want to use a loop for saving:

```
dfs <- Filter(function(x) is.data.frame(get(x)) , noquote(ls()))

[1] a b c
```

But I am not able to write a loop that will make saving properly. Here is an example

```
    for (i in dfs){
      print(i)
      write.csv2(i, paste(i,".csv", sep=""))

}
```

What I want are all files saved on my HD called a.csv, b.csv, c.csv mmm

Comment: `write.csv2(get(i), paste(i,".csv", sep=""))`

Comment: When you write "the environment", do you mean the global environment? Why are these data.frames not in a list?

Comment: they are in the global environment, I import them from xls from a catalog on my HD

Comment: Well, put them into a list during import. Anyway, you need get(i) in your loop.